# Why do chlorophyll need to be dissolved in organic solvents to observe fluorescence?

Tags: organic-chemistry

First, chlorophyll extraction was done with ethanol. I used my phone's flash light to see the fluorescence which was a little pinkish red. Then, I added an ether solvent to the extracted chlorophylls(which contain ethanol), and saw the fluorescence again which was more of a red color than before.

I've learned that chlorophyll dissolve well in ethers than in ethanol, so the fluorescence is higher in an ether solvent. What is the reason for this? There are same amount of chlorophyll but just a different amount of 'how much they are dissolved'. Do chlorophyll need to be 'dissolved' in a solution(organic solvent) to make fluorescence?

Comment: You may be mixing up some concepts. Solubility and fluorescence intensity would be expected to depend on each other (since a higher concentration of the fluorescing substance will initially produce a more intense signal), but the color detected might be shifted by the solvent in a way that has nothing to do with concentration. Is your question why chlorophyll is soluble in organic solvents?

Comment: It is most likely concentration being greater in the ether solution making the fluorescence brighter. Of course if it does not dissolve there is none of it there to fluoresce. Chlorophyll in leaves fluoresces so it does not need an organic solvent.  If it does not dissolve well in a solvent it may aggregate and this quenches any fluorescence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fluorescence color and intensity can be affected by the solvent and dilution of the fluorescent species for a few reasons, including:

- The [state of aggregation](https://atlasofscience.org/fluorescence-color-changes-from-puple-to-blue-via-orange-during-the-solvent-evaporative-crystallization/), e.g., from dissolved to amorphous to crystalline, affects the molecular environment.
- As the concentration changes, [new species may form](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236079727_Fluorescence_Spectral_Changes_of_Perylene_in_Polymer_Matrices_during_the_Solvent_Evaporation_Process).
- The polarity of the solvent affects the [vibrational relaxation time](https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/microscope-resource/primer/java/jablonski/solventeffects/) of the fluorescent solute. Note that ethyl alcohol is far more polar than diethyl ether.